# Possible reasons of choppy video

Tags: encoding

I have a very specific goal: there is a device which is advertised to be able to playback my own media files from USB-pendrive, and I'm intended to do so.

Further details are not disclosed about supported codecs, containers, fps, etc, so I did the easiest way first and tried with a `h264` video in `MP4` container:

```
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media / Version 2
Codec identifier                         : mp42 (isom/mp42)
File size                                : 23,0 MiB
Duration                                 : 6 perc 22 mp
Bitrate                                  : VBR 505 kb/s
gsst                                     : 0
gstd                                     : 382688

Image
Streams                                  : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format profile                           : Main@L3.1
Format settings                          : CABAC / 3 Ref Frames
Codec identifier                         : avc1
Duration                                 : 6 min 22 sec
Bitrate                                  : 373 kb/s
Width                                    : 1280 px
Height                                   : 720 px
Ratio                                    : 16:9
Frame per second                         : fixed, 23,976 (24000/1001) FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bit
Data size                                : 17,0 MiB (74%)
Color range                              : Limited
Color primaries                          : BT.709
Transfer characteristics                 : BT.709
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.709
Codec configuration box                  : avcC

Sound
Streams                                  : 2
Format                                   : AAC LC
Codec identifier                         : mp4a-40-2
Duration                                 : 6 perc 22 mp
Bitrate                                  : VBR, 128 kb/s
Channels                                 : 2
Channel layout                           : L R
Sampling rate                            : 44,1 kHz
Frame per second                         : 43,066 FPS (1024 SPF)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Data size                                : 5,84 MiB (25%)
Language                                 : English
```

Video playback started, but it was choppy, here is a sample (audio is also chopping, in-sync with video):

[image]

This is an in-flight entertainment, so I don't really have too much trials, and I have to prepare before getting onto the plane.

What could be the reason this video is that choppy, and what would you recommend me to try?
Resolution seems reasonable, bitrate is not high, duration not too much, codec is a well-known one.

I would be interested in which parameters might worth changing. I'd put various versions onto a thumbdrive, and give them a test.

Answer (score 2):

There could be many reasons, for example: that device can have very low level hardware decoder or low quality USB port (especially if the device does not come from some widely known and good brand). The first thing I would try is to use the Base codec profile instead of the Main one, the second thing is to downscale the resolution.